# Show that $(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)$ is an unstable fixed point for $\dot{x_1} = -x_1 + x_2^6$, $\dot{x_2} =x_2^3 + x_1^6$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

> Show that $(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)$ is an unstable fixed point for the system $$\dot{x_1} = -x_1 + x_2^6\qquad\dot{x_2} =x_2^3 + x_1^6$$
>   Hint: Consider the Lyapunov function $V(x_1,x_2) = ax_1^i + bx_2^j$.

**What I have done:**
Let $$f(x):={-x_1 + x_2^6 \choose x_2^3 + x_1^6}$$ then
$$\dot V = \nabla V\cdot f(x) = (aix_1^{i-1},bjx_2^{j-1})\cdot{-x_1 + x_2^6 \choose x_2^3 + x_1^6} = aix_1^{i-1}(x_2^6 - x_1) + bjx_2^{j-1}(x_1^6+x_2^3).$$

I have a theorem that basically says that if $\dot V(x) > 0$ for all $x\in E \setminus \{(0,0)\}$, where $E$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ containing $(0,0)$, then $(0,0)$ is unstable.

**Here's my main question**: We were given the hint to consider the given Lyapunov function, but I'm having some difficulty understanding how to use this Lyapunov function to show that basically any nonzero $x\in\mathbb R^2$ gives us that $\dot V(x) > 0$. Must I remain general with the $i$ and $j$, or should I arbitrarily pick $i$ and $j$ in this case? If we don't, then we'd have to break this up into cases, but from what I understand, we just need to *find* a function that satisfies the criteria for the Lyapunov function, not show it works for every possibility.

Comment: Could you check that all the indices are correct? I would expect $\dot x_1=-x_2+x_1^6$ etc.

Comment: @LutzL, it is given as $\dot x_1 = -x_1 + x_2^6$.

Comment: Then for small $x$ the system is a perturbation of $\dot x_1=-x_1$, $x_1(t)=e^{-t}x_1(0)$; and $\dot x_2=x_2^3$, $x_2(t)^{-2}=x_2(0)^{-2}-2t$, $x_2(t)=\frac{x_2(0)}{\sqrt{1-2tx_2(0)^2}}$, which is obviously a saddle point.

Comment: @LutzL Maybe I missed your point, but the system that you've mentioned is not a hyperbolic saddle and to just say that "perturbation of it will have the same behaviour" is not enough.

Comment: There is something very confusing in formulation of this problem. The equilibrium at the origin clearly has one eigenvalue $\lambda$ s.t. ${\rm Re} \, \lambda < 0$, so it has a stable manifold. So it can't be *completely unstable* and you can't use Lyapunov function for proving that it is unstable (Lyapunov's second method works only for stable and completely unstable equilibria). However, there is [Chetaev's function](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Chetaev_function) that can help you prove that there are some directions in which trajectories escape neighbourhood of the origin.

Comment: @Evgeny, this is exactly what I was thinking earlier. I *did* go talk to my professor about the selection of $i, j, a, b$ and interestingly enough, he did mention using Chetaev's function. Somehow we came up with the formulation that $i = 6, j = 4, a = -{1 \over 6}, b={1\over 4}$, which apparently works in some neighborhood of the origin. However, I was never able to make the connection here, nor were any of my other fellow colleagues who saw the exact same problem here.

Comment: Well, if you're worried that $V(x) = \frac{x_2^4 }{4} - \frac{x_1^6}{6}$  *seems to work* here in the same way as Lyapunov function, don't worry: it doesn't have a local minimum or maximum at origin, so it can be only a Chetaev function. I think you can compare graphs from Scholarpedia article with level sets of your function and behaviour of vector field along them, and see a similarity.